# 2 identical javascript's, one working one not

Tags: javascript

I have two identical scripts on two different pages, one works perfectly and one doesn't. Both pages are very similar, some PHP verification and MYSQL queries and a form on each - one page also has another script but no difference if I remove it. Below is the code that is on the pages - the top one works. I have read a bunch of posts regarding issues like this but have not found any answers. I can post code if needed but thought if someone can give me ideas of what to look for first I can avoid that as it is a lot of code. I am not very good at javascript. I just downloaded this one.

Thanks

```
                <button type="button" class='button button-primary' style='width: 25%' onclick="myFunction()">Deploy</button>
            
            <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var myWindow = window.open("deploy.php?hid=<?php echo $hid; ?>", "_self");
            }
            </script>

                <button type="button" class='button button-primary' style='width: 25%' onclick="myFunction()">Admins</button>
            <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var myWindow = window.open("edit_admins.php?record=<?php echo $uid ?>", "_self");
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: What is the actual JS code that this produces? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the second myFunction to something else (along with the associated call of the function)?

Comment: The code just opens the page listed in each of the functions in the same browser window - no errors, just doesn't open the new window. I have tried changing the name of the function, this is one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Note also if I take the one that does work and copy and paste it into the other php script, then it won't work either.

Comment: Got it. Sometimes the smallest details blind you.  In the script that doesn't work, <?php echo $uid ?> should be <?php echo $row['uid']; ?>. Thanks for the help.